# Check if key value is 1 or 2

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefaults, and I am wondering how I can check if the key integer is 0 or 1?

I do not want to check if the key is "nil", but I want to check if it is 0 or 1.

To set the value i used:

```
setValue(value, forKey: "key"
```

Comment: Just to let you know if you don't set a value for your key and use integerForKey it will return 0 (not nil). So if you need to know if a key has been set you will need to use objectForKey

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I want to check the key value.if value is 0: println("0"), if value is 1: println("1"), if value is 2: println("2")..

Comment: If you don't care if it returns nil as 0 my answer is already good for what you want otherwise you need (like I said) to check if NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("key") != nil first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let value = 1

NSUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: "key")

let loadedValue = NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("key")
println(loadedValue)  // 1
if loadedValue == 1 {
    println(true)   // true
} else {
    println(false)
}
```

Comment: The 2 top lines is to set the value, i didn't need that. The rest of the code was what i wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @ole pierre kkkkk That was just for composing the answer. You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber* key = [...];

if (key.integerValue == 1) { ... }
else if (key != nil && key.integerValue == 0) { ... }
else { ... }
```

integerValue will return 0 if key == nil, so if you want to check that the key is present and has a value of 0, you have to check both. When you check for 1, that isn't necessary because the integerValue will not be 1 if key == nil.

In Swift, the easiest way is to check whether the key exists first:

```
if let key = NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("key") {
    if NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("key") == 0 {
    }
}
```